# Copying directory from one location to another in batch script windows

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

Can someone tell me what is wrong with the below. I have defined source location in text file and setting that as a variable and then trying to copy from source to destination

```
set /p source=<%~dp0testloc.txt
set destination=%~dp0
xcopy %source% %destination% /E /y
```

It says invalid path

Although it is pointing out to correct directory
Below is how the command line outputs as

```
C:\Tests>xcopy C:\Users\Hussain\Downloads\TestData\ C:\Tests\ /E /y
Invalid path
```

Comment: Are you sure `C:\Users\Hussain\Downloads\TestData\` exists and has appropriate permissions?

Comment: The directory is available and has sufficient permissions but the xcopy weirdly doesn't work. I have changed the location to C:\ works fine. Weird!.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The behaviour is consistent with the source directory not existing, as you can see what happened on my PC:

```
Prompt>xcopy C:\Users\Gebruiker\Downloads\TestData\ C:\Tests\ /E /y
Invalid path
0 File(s) copied

Prompt>mkdir C:\Users\Gebruiker\Downloads\TestData\

Prompt>xcopy C:\Users\Gebruiker\Downloads\TestData\ C:\Tests\ /E /y
0 File(s) copied
```

Comment: The directory is available and has sufficient permissions but the xcopy weirdly doesn't work. I have changed the location to C:\ works fine. Weird!